# How to disable browser's popup blockers using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, popup, popupwindow

I want to block the browser's default popup blockers using javascript or jquery.
I've found a few solutions, but they don't work for Chrome/Opera. It oly works for Mozilla Firefox. I'm using this jQuery solution right now:

```
    // Attach click event to the link
    $('#popup_openbox_blocked').click(function() {
            // window.open() works here because it is initiated by an user's click action
            // We prefer window.open() to the anchor's href action because we want to save the return reference from window.open
            var new_window = window.open("http://google.ro", "", "");
            popup.close(); // Close the custom alert. Won't work unless you have popup() defined
            return false;
    });

    var newWin = window.open();
    newWin.location = "http://google.ro";
```

How can I deactivate the browser's popup blocker for Chrome and Opera using jquery/javascript?

Comment: You cannot otherwise there would be no reason for web browser to implement such a functionality in first place. The popup blocker can be desactivated in user browser's preference, but that's nothing to do with javascript. For a popup to not be blocked, page needs some user interaction, as clicking anywhere on page

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any solution for opening multiple windows using jquery/javascript at the same time (and I mean windows not dialogs)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no more solution on chrome (FF still should have). The old trick was to dispatch click event on some temp anchor tags but like i said, if i'm correct, this no more working in chrome (opera???)

Comment: I've tried this solution but it's not working.

Comment: hey @Pascut,
did you get the solution for this ?